# Network Manager "forgets" my network

Tags: networking, kde, networkmanager

It's been a long time since I last tampered with Linux desktop, and I wanted to see how it's doing, so I put KDE Neon on an old laptop. It works very well and I find it amazing, however I bumped into a weird annoyance concerning wifi.
When I boot the machine it correctly connects to my wifi network (ordinary router, default settings, always worked with every device). After a while it shows a notification saying "Connection {{my_network}} deactivated". When I click on system tray wifi icon it shows all available networks except mine.
I tried scanning network from command line with `nmcli dev wifi` but it yields the same result: all networks are listed except mine. I also tried restarting Network Manager with `sudo service network-manager restart`, to no avail. The connection is restored upon reboot.
What's happening here? Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I have seen this or similar problems hundreds of times and have not find a precise solution, I can only share my experience. Wifi is the softest spot in Linux, the only one that sometimes makes me regret Windows etc;. there seems to be a combination of both hardware (I guess there are laptops that are not at all affected), desktop environment (gnome and gnome-related desktops seem less affected afaikt) and kernel/OS version (latest versions seem less affected).

Comment: Neon is now 16.04 based - and that seems the most affected (https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/47206). But I would say desktop is very important. I would try newest ubuntu that comes in a few days (or kubuntu), or wait for Neon to go to 18.04 There are great chances this will be fixed. What I can say is that KDE above ubuntu 16.04 was not affected especially compared to kde and xfce in 16.04. That unity, gnome, elementary and budgie were less affected; seemed already fixed for me in 18.04.beta. Non-ubuntu linux much less chances to be affected.

Comment: Summing up: from my experience: ubuntu 16.04 + Plasma5 = the most risky combination. My wifi was disconnecting randomly in most cases, but only in **that** combination I have seen even my password being forgotten. (Fixable with resetting network or restart etc). At the present I use elementary (ubuntu16.04-based) and solus (rolling) and I don't have the problem.